# How to set a shortcut for multiple leader commands

Tags: key-bindings, comments, plugin-nerdcommenter

I'm using the [nerdcommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) to comment and uncomment my c++ code.

Basically I use `\cc` to comment one line, `\cu` to uncomment, `\ca` to switch the delimiters (switch `//` to `/**/` or switch back).

Now I want to set a shortcut named `\cv` for this case:

```
\cv: \ca + \cc + \ca
```

so that I can use the other delimiter quickly.

I've tried to add `nnoremap <leader>cv <leader>ca \| <leader>cc \| <leader>\ca` into my `~/.vimrc` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
nmap <leader>cv <leader>ca<leader>cc<leader>ca
```

Note that you can't use `nore`-stuff here.

Comment: Great it works. May I know why?

Comment: @Yves Because this mapping **does** depend on the other mapping(s). While all `noremap` commands effectively ignore all other mappings and allow to use only "standard" commands on the right-hand side. Usually this is preferred, as this prevents the conflicts between mappings, but not in this case. BTW. If the plugin also exports some functions or <plug>s with the desired functionality, then, as a matter of style, it's better to map to them rather than to "the hotkeys". This way it would be harder (or even imposssible) to break the things up with some other `nmap`.